# Alter first vertical grid line in nvd3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I want to remove (or make effectively hidden) the first vertical line in the grid for an nvd3 chart. I thought it was a problem with my chart, but after testing it, I realized it seems to be a more general problem.

I tested it by running the line:

```
d3.selectAll('.tick, .nv-axislabel, .nv-axis text').attr('fill','#999999')
```

in the console, at the simplest line chart I could find: http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html and it still didn't work! It changes all the lines *except* the very first vertical line. I'm baffled, I've tried every combination of classes with stroke, fill, opacity, etc - I can either affect the entire svg (with opacity), or nothing. Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

I should have specified this originally, I apologize - I do not want to remove the Y axis entirely. I still need the label and the tick marks - I just want to remove that one vertical line (or at least lighten it - it is much darker than the rest of my chart).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by your comments:
You don't want to see the *" the first vertical line in the grid for an nvd3 chart"*
Which is the y axis:
Two ways to achieve that:
Option1

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                .margin({left: 100})  //Adjust chart margins to give the x-axis some breathing room.
                .useInteractiveGuideline(true)  //We want nice looking tooltips and a guideline!
                .transitionDuration(350)  //how fast do you want the lines to transition?
                .showLegend(true)       //Show the legend, allowing users to turn on/off line series.
                .showYAxis(false)        //hide the y-axis
                .showXAxis(true);        //Show the x-axis
```

Option2:
Since in your example you are going for a CSS option

```
d3.selectAll('.nv-y').attr('display','none')
```

I will prefer Option1

**EDIT** post your clarification, you wish to make the y axis line light you can use:

```
d3.selectAll('.nv-y path').attr('opacity','0.1')
```

or if you want to hide it completely

```
d3.selectAll('.nv-y path').attr('display','none')
```

Comment: I should have specified this originally, I apologize - I do not want to remove the Y axis entirely. I still need the label and the tick marks - I just want to remove that one vertical line (or at least lighten it - it is much darker than the rest of my chart).

Comment: @ChrisBurrus i have updated my answer check the **EDIT** section

Comment: That was it, thanks! Any chance of any documentation for that? I couldn't find it anywhere, and was hoping to use it for reference in the future.

Comment: Hi @Cyril would you mind a look at my question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852062/how-to-hide-first-y-axis-line-on-an-nvd3-chart I tried your solutions, however my first y axis border line still shows up.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to specify an array of tick values that you want to use for each axis. Use `axis.tickValues([values])` to explicitly declare which XAxis ticks you want for your graph. So you could pop `.tickValues([1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]);` into either the `chart.xAxis` or the `chart.yAxis`, and ticks would only appear from the corresponding values in the array. In your case, you would want to put it in the `chart.xAxis` variable.  However if you want to have a dynamic chart, explicitly declaring the tick values would pose a problem once the data is updated in the graph. If on the other hand you are using static data, this is a pretty easy fix. I've tested this solution in their live code editor and it seems to do the trick.

Refer to https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#ticks to see some other directives that could be of use.

Comment: I don't entirely understand how this removes the vertical line. In either case though, we unfortunately do have dynamic tick values, so I don't think this will help for my case.